# Plotly: how to change the position of the display

Tags: python, html, plotly

I'm very new to Dash. Just trying to move around.

```
from dash import Dash,html,dcc,Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_daq as daq
app.layout = html.Div([
                        html.H1('Billboard'),
                        dcc.Interval(id='input_place'),


                        html.Div([daq.LEDDisplay(
                                        label="Distance",
                                        labelPosition='top',
                                        value=55.99
                        )],style={'width': '25%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding': '0 0'})
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Output of this is above
[image]

I just want to move to the center ? how to do that.
thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called assets, then create a css file called header.css with the following

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center
}
```